# Create a Batch file that runs as administrator then renew the ip address

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a domain network, and I am working on organizing the IP addresses on this domain using DHCP. Sometimes I need to shut down the server for some maintenance, then turn it on again, so when I do some end users get their IP's wrong, they just need to renew the addresses or press "Diagnose" in the local area connection status.

I don't want to waste my time following up each host to diagnose their ip addresses to get them fixed, so I thought about a way to sum it all up in a double click, but google doesn't seem to be helping me this time.
The steps are the following (from the cmd / batch):

1-enable administrative privileges

2-ipconfid /release

3-ipconfig /renew

4-convert the .txt into .bat

I am not sure that there is a step between 1 and 2, if it is mandatory to state the echo on/off.
But what I want to be sure of is, when I open the cmd, then I want to enable the administrative rights to open the local area connection status, and then do the rest.
As I could see that the code to open a file through admin rights is

`runas /profile /user:administrator “HERE THE NAME OF THE FILE TO OPEN”`

But there is no need to open a specific file to edit them, so if you could help me find the way just to run as admin through the cmd and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Powershell from batch file to invoke another batch file to run under elevated privilege.

*Launcher.bat*

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& { Start-Process "C:\Users\..\AdminProc.bat"  -Verb Runas}"
```

*AdminProc.bat*

```
# Run any task that requires elevated privilege.
Net Stop "Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)"
```

In second batch file you can run the `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` with anyother command.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat or .cmd file past the below save and run as Admin

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

arp -d *

nbtstat -R

nbtstat -RR

ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /registerdns

exit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33827816)